# Where can I find open APIs with wine data (such as numerical expert rating)?

Tags: wine

I'm looking for a wine API with basic info (producer name, name, varietal, region, expert rating, description). Wine.com seems to have deprecated their API last month. I can't find any other ones from sites like WineEnthusiast and WineAdvocate.

Wine-searcher.com has one, but it costs $350 a month and they won't give it to me temporarily (I'm just a student building a prototype app).

Anybody know of any?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate that has no answer https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/are-there-any-public-apis-that-will-help-determine-the-legality-of-a-location-to

Comment: FYI, people spend a lot of time writing and rating wines and they don't want to give that information for free. Would  you want to give away your app for free after you finish writing it? Just the way things are...

Comment: @SteveS. And yet, according to the question, they had this information online and available until recently.

Comment: @Phillipp people just trying to monetize their intellectual property. Looks like wine.com is going out of business. I know that on some sites like Cellar Tracker you can see scores but the API is mainly for the bottles in your cellar. When I was selling wine, I used to download scores from Wine Spectator, but it was a manual process. I think the best thing you can do is some type of screen scraping program. Sorry but in my brief search of the internet it looks like there is nothing and it's something that you simply won't find for free.

Comment: I vote to close, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can find (and am currently aware of) is [LCBO API](https://lcboapi.com/). This free API provides details for products sold through the gov't owned liquor retailer in Ontario, Canada. They have a fairly large selection as they are one of the [largest buyers of alcohol products globally](http://www.lcbo.com/content/lcbo/en/corporate-pages/about.html#.WfyTM9WnG70).

By providing a product's [SKU code](http://www.lcbo.com/) to the API, you can retrieve some of the product details you're looking for except rating, and varietal. As a consolation, it does provide details on wine type (red, white, rose, champagne etc.) and country (incl. region for some products), but doesn't provide details such as Chardonnay, Sauvignon Blanc, Cabernet Merlot, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...it's free, you just have to create an account and request an api key...
https://www.globalwinescore.com/api/

Comment: This is an interesting one. It seems like there are very few wines in their database, but it is promising.

Comment: I looked GWS. They do not give you the actual score. They "calculate" a score based on other wine critics. It also seems like they have only 50 wines in their database. So, if you want to actually look for Wine Advocate or Wine Spectator scores, you'll need to keep looking. I told you, nobody of value will give away scores for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free Global Wine Score API: https://www.globalwinescore.com/api/. The api returns a score for each wine along with other practical info (producer, region, etc.).

We have a database of over 26,000 wine scores which are calculated as an average from major wine critics. You can read more about it here: https://www.globalwinescore.com/calculation/.

If you have any questions please reach out to us at contact@globalwinescore.com. Cheers!

Comment: Again, as I said a few months ago, it's an average of scores. You don't know what a particular critic scored it and in the USA there are only 50 wines?!?!? what use is that to anyone?

Comment: There are over 26,000 wine scores, not just 50. I am not sure where you got that number? You are correct that we cannot share the individual critic scores, but the global wine score shows a consensus of expert opinions including those from Wine Advocate and Wine Spectator like mentioned above.

Comment: There are not 26,000 wine scores because you aggregate them into an average. Are you restricting your searches to 50 hits because when I sort on USA and Red I only get 50 hits.

Comment: There are actually 26,000 Global Wine Scores (aggregated score) composed from over 350,000 wine scores from critics. If you are not signed in the search is restricted, but with a free account you can view all of the scores. You can also access them for free via the API after requesting an API key.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for this information but I found this list on programmableweb.com, https://www.programmableweb.com/category/wine/api

Hope it helps.

Comment: We looked at this when this question was answered. Most of the links are old and dead, don't pertain to this question or cost money.